# Как изменить изображение метки при наведении на список в yandex map

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты, yandexmapkit, yandex-geocoding-api

Отличный пример Yandex путешествия.
При наведение на элемент списка изменяется иконка на карте для этого элемента.
Каким образом можно добиться такого результата с yandex api?

[Yandex путешествия](https://travel.yandex.ru/hotels/search/?adults=2&bbox=37.173512809678485%2C54.75417826182016%7E39.94478527765598%2C56.454395356718635&checkinDate=2022-03-30&checkoutDate=2022-03-31&childrenAges=&geoId=213&lastSearchTimeMarker=1648461707077&navigationToken=0&searchPagePollingId=7fc6e832a7c49095ee9d5b86fa05b8b2-5-newsearch&selectedSortId=relevant-first)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В песочнице Яндекса есть пример [смены значка метки при наведении](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/event_rollover). В вашем  случае нужно изменять параметры метки при наведении на другой объект страницы, для этого достаточно лишь изменить объект, события которого нужно прослушивать. А перенести метку на передний план можно через изменение её  [zIndex](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Placemark.html#Placemark__param-options.zIndex).

Comment: Да, примеры видел. 
Получись добиться этого через iconContentLayout с помощью отслеживания изменений this.getData().geoObject.events.add('propertieschange', () => {});